# Problem updating plymouth bootscreen theme

Tags: boot, themes, plymouth

I've made a new theme based on ("/usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo").

Simply changed all the purple into blue. I've updated the .plymouth (bluebuntu.plymouth) file and script:

ImageDir=/usr/share/plymouth/themes/bluebuntu

ScriptFile=/usr/share/plymouth/themes/bluebuntu/bluebuntu.script

Then I ran:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth default.plymouth /usr/share/plymouth/themes/bluebuntu/bluebuntu.plymouth 100
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

(Selected my new theme: /usr/share/plymouth/themes/bluebuntu/bluebuntu.plymouth)

Then ran:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

The problem is the bootscreen is still showing the purple version...
I even tried changing the names of all the .png files in case it's caching it based on name or something, but it doesn't work.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got it, I should have edited the new "bluebuntu.script" to this:

```
Window.SetBackgroundTopColor (0, 0.09, 0.14);     
Window.SetBackgroundBottomColor (0, 0.09, 0.14);
```

And then:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

No more purple! (no that there's anything wrong with that)